# Passing a search parameter to a query fails

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Am new to sqlite and performing a query with

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE locations = "+ appdd;
```

THe value of appdd is passed in the function like

```
    public List<MaterialsModel> getLocationMaterials(String applock) {
       String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE locations = "+ applock; 

    ...other sqlite commands
    }
```

Whenever i run the above am getting an error

```
SQLiteException: no such column: appdd (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * 
    FROM tbl_test WHERE locations = applock
```

Where am i going wrong as `applock` is a stribng dynamically passed in the function

Comment: Similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49065931/4904995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE locations = '"+ applock + "'";`

Because applock is query string, must put inside single quote.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in single quotes.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE locations = '"+ applock + "'";
```

[Android SQLite Database Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score -1):

first Check whether Database is created or not.
use this lib to see your sqlite database

`debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.3'`

details for this lib please visit [here](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database)

and replace your query with this

`String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE locations = '"+ applock + "'";`